Local-to-global ransformations for angular velocity
I have a robot on a 2.5d surface. i assume that robot doesn't flip, so gimbal lock is not a problem.
For a robot, I know:
linear velocity (local frame)
angular velocity (local frame)
the two above come from teleop command.
I also know roll, pitch and yaw in a global frame.
Question: how to get global angular velocity (wx, wy, wz)?
Please help.
P.S. Just in case: this question is a part of an attempt to calculate robot's next position from the current one and teleop command, it will be used by UKF for localization.
Here is the code, and the line i am struggling with is
wGlobal = transform_angular_velocity(wLocal, [roll, pitch, yaw])

If by any chance you can suggest a better way of doing it, it would be even better.
Here is the code itself:
def getNextState(self, x, dt, u):
        # Unpack the state
        xPos, yPos, zPos, roll, pitch, yaw, vx, vy, vz, wxLocal, wyLocal, wzLocal, ax, ay, az, slip_linear, slip_angular = x
        xPosPrev, yPosPrev, zPosPrev = xPos, yPos, zPos

        # Control inputs, local frame
        vel_linear = u[0]
        vel_angular = u[1]

        # No slippage. Only used to draw "perfect" trajectory.
        if(self.nSlip == 0):
            pass

        # Slippage calculated by Kalman filter
        elif(self.nSlip == 1):
            vel_linear = vel_linear * slip_linear
            vel_angular = vel_angular * slip_angular
            
        # Simulate slippage in entire area
        elif(self.nSlip == 2):
            vel_linear *= 0.5
            vel_angular *= 0.2
        # Simulate slippage in selected rectangles only
        elif(self.nSlip == 3):
            for rect in self.arrSlippers:
                if((rect[0] <= x[0] <= rect[0] + rect[2]) and (rect[1] <= x[1] <= rect[1] + rect[3])):
                    vel_linear *= 0.5
                    vel_angular *= 0.2
                    break  

        # ---

        # wLocal = [wxLocal, wyLocal, vel_angular]
        wLocal = [0, 0, vel_angular]
        #wGlobal = transform(wLocal, [roll, pitch, yaw], LOCAL_TO_GLOBAL)
        wGlobal = transform_angular_velocity(wLocal, [roll, pitch, yaw])
        
        # Update yaw (local yaw)
        rpy_new = normalize_angle([
            roll + wGlobal[0] * dt, 
            pitch + wGlobal[1] * dt,
            yaw + wGlobal[2] * dt
        ])

        # ---

        vLocal = np.array([vel_linear, 0, 0])
        vGlobal = transform(vLocal, rpy_new, LOCAL_TO_GLOBAL)
        #vGlobal = transform(vLocal, [roll, pitch, yaw], False)

        vx_new, vy_new, vz_new = vGlobal

        # Calculate accelerations
        ax = (vx_new - vx) / dt
        ay = (vy_new - vy) / dt
        az = (vz_new - vz) / dt

        xPos += vx_new * dt
        yPos += vy_new * dt
        #zPos += vz_new * dt
        zPos = self.surface_func(xPos, yPos)

        # if(pos_new != prev_pos):
        if(self.bUseGetRPY):
            pos_new = [xPos, yPos]
            prev_pos = [xPosPrev, yPosPrev]
            rpy_new = self.getRPY(prev_pos, pos_new, yaw, vel_angular * dt)

        roll_new, pitch_new, yaw_new = rpy_new

        # Calculate angular velocities (approximation: finite difference)
        wxGlobal = (roll_new - roll) / dt
        wyGlobal = (pitch_new - pitch) / dt
        wzGlobal = (yaw_new - yaw) / dt

        wxLocal, wyLocal, wzLocal = transform([wxGlobal, wyGlobal, wzGlobal], rpy_new, GLOBAL_TO_LOCAL)

        # Prepare and return the new state vector
        return np.array([xPos, yPos, zPos, roll_new, pitch_new, yaw_new, vx_new, vy_new, vz_new,
            wxLocal, wyLocal, wzLocal, ax, ay, az, slip_linear, slip_angular])

def transform_angular_velocity(w, rpy, nGlobalToLocal):
    
    roll, pitch, yaw = rpy
    
    # Create the transformation matrix
    T = np.array([
        [1, 0, -np.sin(pitch)],
        [0, np.cos(roll), np.cos(pitch) * np.sin(roll)],
        [0, -np.sin(roll), np.cos(pitch) * np.cos(roll)]
    ])
    
    if(nGlobalToLocal == LOCAL_TO_GLOBAL):
        # Local to global: apply inverse of T
        w_transformed = np.linalg.inv(T) @ w
    elif(nGlobalToLocal == GLOBAL_TO_LOCAL):
        # Global to local: apply T directly
        w_transformed = T @ w
    else:
        raise ValueError("Direction must be 'local_to_global' or 'global_to_local'")
    
    return w_transformed

def euler_to_rotation_matrix(roll, pitch, yaw):
    """
    Create the rotation matrix for transforming angular velocities between the local and global frames
    based on the robot's roll, pitch, and yaw angles.
    """
    # Rotation matrix for yaw (around z-axis)
    R_yaw = np.array([
        [np.cos(yaw), -np.sin(yaw), 0],
        [np.sin(yaw), np.cos(yaw), 0],
        [0, 0, 1]
    ])

    # Rotation matrix for pitch (around y-axis)
    R_pitch = np.array([
        [np.cos(pitch), 0, np.sin(pitch)],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [-np.sin(pitch), 0, np.cos(pitch)]
    ])

    # Rotation matrix for roll (around x-axis)
    R_roll = np.array([
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(roll), -np.sin(roll)],
        [0, np.sin(roll), np.cos(roll)]
    ])

    # Combined rotation matrix: R = R_yaw * R_pitch * R_roll
    R = R_yaw @ R_pitch @ R_roll
    return R

def get_rotation_matrix(rpy):
    roll, pitch, yaw = rpy
    
    # Create a rotation matrix from roll, pitch, yaw using tf_transformations
    return tf_transformations.euler_matrix(roll, pitch, yaw, 'rxyz')[:3, :3]
    #return tf_transformations.euler_matrix(roll, pitch, yaw)[:3, :3]

# ---

def global_to_local(global_vec, rpy):
    # Get the rotation matrix for the robot's orientation (RPY)
    rotation_matrix = get_rotation_matrix(rpy)

    #local_vec = np.matmul(rotation_matrix.T, global_vec)
    local_vec = np.matmul(np.linalg.inv(rotation_matrix), global_vec)

    return local_vec

# ---

def local_to_global(local_vec, rpy):
    # Get the rotation matrix for the robot's orientation (RPY)
    rotation_matrix = get_rotation_matrix(rpy)

    # Apply the rotation matrix to the angular velocity
    global_vec = np.dot(rotation_matrix, local_vec)

    return global_vec

# ---    

def transform(arrVector, arrRobotOrientation, nGlobalToLocal):
    if nGlobalToLocal:
        return global_to_local(arrVector, arrRobotOrientation)
    else:    
        return local_to_global(arrVector, arrRobotOrientation)

    def getRPY(self, prev_pos, pos, yaw_prev, deltaYawLocal):
        x, y = pos
        x_prev, y_prev = prev_pos
        step = 0.01
        
        yaw = yaw_prev + deltaYawLocal

        # If there is movement, proceed with the regular calculation
        if x == x_prev and y == y_prev:
            delta_x = step * np.cos(yaw)
            delta_y = step * np.sin(yaw)
            
            # Update x, y with the small movement
            x = x_prev + delta_x
            y = y_prev + delta_y

        # Calculate surface gradients (partial derivatives of surface function)
        dz_dx = (self.surface_func(x + step, y) - self.surface_func(x - step, y)) / (2 * step)
        dz_dy = (self.surface_func(x, y + step) - self.surface_func(x, y - step)) / (2 * step)

        # Calculate movement vector
        move_vector = np.array([x - x_prev, y - y_prev])
        
        # # Calculate yaw from movement vector
        # #yaw = np.arctan2(move_vector[1], move_vector[0])
        # yaw = yaw_prev + deltaYawLocal
        
        # Calculate the movement direction in the x-y plane
        move_dir = move_vector / np.linalg.norm(move_vector)
        
        # Calculate pitch (angle between the surface normal and the horizontal plane)
        pitch = -np.arctan2(dz_dx * move_dir[0] + dz_dy * move_dir[1], 1)
        
        # Calculate roll (tilt perpendicular to the movement direction)
        move_perp = np.array([-move_dir[1], move_dir[0]])
        roll = -np.arctan2(dz_dx * move_perp[0] + dz_dy * move_perp[1], 1)
        
        return np.array([roll, pitch, yaw])

What I do: I have a map and robot's previous and current positions. So I can calculate RPY from that.

If I understand your question correctly, I think I ran into this at one point in the EKF for robot_localization. I was previously transforming the rotational velocities using the same math as I did for linear velocity, but that's not correct. Here's the commit where I fixed it:
https://github.com/cra-ros-pkg/robot_localization/commit/58bef056cf84856eb5e91a89f643017c448669ff
Note that I am going from body-frame velocity to world-frame Euler angles, but I think the math should be the same, just without the multiplication by the time delta.
For example, the equation for pitch for the platform would be
new_pitch_world = previous_pitch_world + cos(roll_world) * pitch_velocity_body * time_delta - sin(roll_world) * yaw_velocity * time_delta

Simplifying a bit, we can see that
pitch_velocity_world = cos(roll_world) * pitch_velocity_body - sin(roll_world) * yaw_velocity

Unfortunately, I forget how I derived the math for this one, and failed to note any learning material I used.
